# Variable Scope inside a promise jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

Imagine you are doing the following inside a javascript function called Fetch.

```
function Fetch(context)
{
  var request = $.ajax({...});
  request.done(function(response)
  {
    // it looks like context is visible here and in Scope.
    //
  });
```

}

Can you explain why context is visible inside the callback function.?

Comment: context is visible for everything inside the Fetch method.

Comment: Because it's declared in the parent of your done function. Any vars declared in the Fetch function will be available to any functions used in it.

Comment: Because that's how closures work. Every function has access to the variables defined in the same or in a higher scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`context` is local to `Fetch`. `request` is declared inside of `Fetch`, therefore `context` is available inside `request`